# "The type 'XDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" error even though reference exists

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am writing some C# unit tests using [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/introduction) for a work project. As I was debugging the unit tests, I ran the statement

```
internalModel.GetSections().First().GetTextAreas().First().Content.Should().NotBe("someContent","Some reason");
```

(Obviously I've changed the class and method names so as not to expose proprietary code.)

This produced an error:
`The type 'XDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.XDocument, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

I searched through the assemblies referenced in the project dependencies, and System.Xml.XDocument was there:

[image]

Also, these using statements are included in my file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Evaluating just the first part of the expression (`internalModel.GetSections().First().GetTextAreas().First().Content`) gave me the correct result (i.e. the content of the text area) so the problem must be with the `Should()` method.
However, there are other unit tests in the same class that also use this method, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Here are the contents of the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="JUnitTestLogger" Version="1.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\InternalProject.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\OtherInternalProject.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you add more details, csproj file content for example?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just added the contents of the csproj file. Please let me know if there are any other details I should add.